# What version of C++ am I using?

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

I am taking a C++ Programming class, 2/2 of the C++ classes my university offers, and I asked my professor which version of C++ we are using and he does not know.

I have looked around on here and found a bunch of different  answers based on G++ not supporting some versions and supporting some of this version of C++, and so on-...

*My general question:*

1. What version of C++ am I using?
2. What versions of C++ can I use?
3. Advantages and disadvantages of C++ version I am using?
4. Should I even worry about the different versions of C++ right now?

Output for `g++ --version`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

My current version G++ Compiler: 4.2.1

IDE: Eclipse C++ 2020-03

OS: MacOSX MoJave

*Snippet of code we use for class:*

```
void find(int IDs[], string posts[], int size)
{
    int search = -9999;
    bool found = false;
    cout << "Enter user ID: " << endl;
    cin >> search;

    while (search < 0)
    {
        cout << "In-correct ID Type" << endl;
        cout << "Enter user ID: " << endl;
        cin >> search;
    }
    cout << "Posts by user " << search << ":" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (IDs[i] == search)
        {
            cout << *(posts + i);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found == false)
    {
        cout << "N/A posts for user " << search << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: *My current version G++ Compiler: 4.2.1* -- That is a *very* old version.

Comment: If it really is g++ 4.2.1 then I don't think that event supported c++11 so you're probably stuck with c++03.  Since this is on Mac OS can you edit your question to show the output of `g++ --version` .

Comment: @G.M. - Made the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What version of C++ am I using ?

If you're using default settings, probably **GNU C++ 98** ( NOTE: Not the same as **(standard) ISO C++ 98** )

> 2. What versions of C++ can I use?

gcc 4.2.4 only supports **ISO C++ 98** and **GNU C++ 98**

> 3. Advantages and disadvantages of C++ version I am using?

The first ISO standardized version, published around 1998 as the name suggests.
Major revisions have been released since.

Very old and clunky but still largely present in the industry.

Later revisions make the language considerably more elegant and easy to use,
also use of at least ISO C++ 11 (2011) (also called *Modern C++*) or later revisions, when possible, is considered best practice.

> 4. Should I even worry about the different versions of C++ right now?

If you taken the class to mainly learn about the language rather than programming fundamentals...

and especially if you plan to actively use the language out of the class...

YES

but since learning later revisions details' can be challenging, at least know what are the major differences for now.

--

References: [gcc 4.2.4 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-std_003d-653)

Comment: I am running it from Eclipse MacOSX GCC compiler, and when I run my code I run it in the IDE... so would that make a difference?

Comment: Consider that a language, as well as an IDE, is merely a tool. As a programmer you should be able to choose the most appropriate tool to fulfill your goals and, as far as possible, not let the tool arbitrarily constrain you. In this case, if you want to claim to know how to use c++, you should be able to tell if a specific ( or the available, more frequently ) version is suited for what you need to do. Also i think that by the end of class you want to know the c++ language itself more than GCC or Eclipse, and eventually be able to seamlessly switch to another implementation if you want.

Comment: As a side note: I consider it serious that the professor said he didn't know. Like, he wants to teach you something, but he doesn't know what he's teaching you?

Comment: Very intelligent but he just said he never cared to look.

Answer (score 2):

From the output of `g++ --version`...

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

it appears you are actually using `clang++` 10.0.1.  That should be good for language specs. up to and including c++17 according to [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp17) as well as a few selected c++20 features.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [gcc 4.2.4 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-std_003d-653):

> standard may be one of:
>   *...other options omitted for brevity...*
>   - *c++98*
>       The 1998 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.
>   - *gnu++98*
>       The same as -std=c++98 plus GNU extensions. This is the default for C++ code.

No other options are given for a valid version of C++.

**Your default version of C++ is:** C++98 (plus gnu extensions! whatever that means)

**Your options of possible C++ versions are:** C++98 (plus gnu extensions)

Comment: so you are saying I am using C++ 98?

Comment: I believe so, yes.